# What determines how many merit points a lost satchel is worth?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

Whenever I find another player's lost satchel I'm awarded Merit Points. The amount of points I earn is different for each satchel. What determines how many Merit Points a lost satchel is worth?

[image: A lost satchel]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lost Satchels are worth 50 Merit Points plus 2.5 points (rounded down) for each type of item in the satchel.**

I [created a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wJfkNNxSuyyzYPaQuEw8mkmLk42yFfKwmBGiU29MKv4/edit?usp=sharing) documenting the number of items, item type, location, and Merit Points for 30 lost satchels. Each satchel was worth at least 50 Merit Points with an extra 2 or 3 points for each item type. So for example:

- 1 item = 52 Merit Points
- 2 items = 55 Merit Points
- 3 items = 57 Merit Points
- 4 items = 60 Merit Points

[image: Satchel point amounts]